# Windows: List files and their permissions (access) in command line

Tags: windows, command-line

In linux, `ls -l` lists files permissions, like this:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 user user      924 2011-07-01 20:23 test.txt
```

In Windows, commands `tree` and `dir` don't have the options to list permissions. How is it possible to list files and their permissions using command line only?

Comment: Uh, maybe [`%~aX`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667026), if it's in batch? It's like `d----------`.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use [**icacls**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525.aspx):

```
> icacls Music
Music SNOW\grawity:(I)(F)
      CREATOR OWNER:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
      SNOW\grawity:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
      NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
```

The older [**cacls**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490872.aspx) tool is the only choice on Windows XP [although you can copy `icacls.exe` from Server 2003]. *cacls* does not know about some ACL modes, but displays most of them fine.

```
> cacls Music
F:\Users\Mantas\Music SNOW\grawity:F
                      CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)F
                      SNOW\grawity:(OI)(CI)(IO)F
                      NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)F
```

In both outputs, `(OI)` means "object inherit" (files will inherit this ACE), `(CI)` is "container inherit" (containers – i.e. folders – will inherit this ACE), `(IO)` is "inherit only".

Microsoft also used to provide an [*xcacls*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318754) tool separately, but its functionality is now part of *icacls*.

Answer (score 37):

You can use Powershell and the [`Get-Acl`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849802.aspx) command

```
PS C:\> Get-Acl

   Directory:

Path              Owner                            Access  
----              -----                            ------  
C:\               NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller      Everyone Allow  FullControl
```

Use it in conjunction with [`Get-ChildItem`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx) (aliased with `dir` and `ls`) to get the permissions for the files.

```
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem | Get-Acl
```

Or, using the alias:

```
PS C:\> Dir | Get-Acl
```

Comment: `PS C:\> Get-Acl | fl` for a nicer list.

Comment: Can I alter this to skip a folder that I don't have access to? for example, when I ran this (not as admin) I got an error ("unauthorized operation") and the report stopped at the folder I did not have access to

Answer (score 16):

You might also take a look at [AccessChk](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb664922) from Sysinternals.
The output can be parsed much easier.

```
C:\Users\jeremy>accesschk myad\simmonsj c:\inetpub

Accesschk v5.11 - Reports effective permissions for securable objects
Copyright (C) 2006-2012 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

RW c:\inetpub\custerr
RW c:\inetpub\history
RW c:\inetpub\logs
RW c:\inetpub\Roadkill
RW c:\inetpub\smartadmin
RW c:\inetpub\temp
RW c:\inetpub\wwwroot
```

Comment: It does a different thing though; it lists the _effective_ access for the current (or specified) user, rather than the full _configured_ access list.

Comment: I believe the OP's question could have been interpreted either way. Judging by the recent up-vote on my answer, this was useful to at least one other person besides me. My answer is not meant to argue with or disprove your answer. It is a different way to approach the problem to get a very similar answer.

Answer (score 10):

`dir /Q` gives you the owner of the directories and of any files in the current folder.

With `dir /Q /S` you can see the owners of all files and directories in and under the current folder.

Thanks @DAB for the edit suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want Windows file attributes (not ownership or ACLs) you can use the Powershell Dir command (a shortcut for the [Get-ChildItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2) command). For example:

```
...>powershell dir


    Directory: C:\...


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        09/04/2022     18:09                testfiles
-a----        08/04/2022     23:19         130844 testbbackupd.cpp
-a----        08/04/2022     23:19             94 testextra
-a----        09/04/2022     18:06        8394752 test_bbackupd.exe
```

The letters in the Mode property are the Windows file attributes of each file, which [can be interpreted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2#example-1-get-child-items-from-a-file-system-directory) as follows:

- l (link)
- d (directory)
- a (archive)
- r (read-only)
- h (hidden)
- s (system).

Comment: I downvoted because that's not what OP wanted. They unambiguously stated they wanted to see file permissions. This answer is better suited as a comment.