# matching dir /a:r and icacls

Tags: windows-7, command-line, permissions, icacls

I am trying to see file permissions on command line. I came across [a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/364083/windows-list-files-and-their-permissions-access-in-command-line) but cannot understand `icacls` output.

In the following example, `c10.dat` is a read-only file, as shown by `dir /a:r` and the error in overwriting it with `dir > c10.dat`.

In the `icacls` output `DOMAIN\USER` is placeholder for my own id. How does it indicate that `c10.dat` is a read-only file? From what I understand its acls mean `(I)` inherited and `(F)` full-access.

```
X:\>dir /a:r c10.dat
 Volume in drive X is OSDisk
 Volume Serial Number is 6621-4FA8

 Directory of X:\

04/08/2013  11:11 AM             8,192 c10.dat
               1 File(s)          8,192 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  40,525,492,224 bytes free

X:\>icacls c10.dat
c10.dat NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
        BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
        DOMAIN\USER:(I)(F)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

X:\>dir > c10.dat
Access is denied.
```

Comment: The file attributes (like read-only) and permissions are completely different things. The icacls command shows the file's ACLs.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMarshall. It seems I misunderstood the other question and its answer. Is there a way to find a file's read-only attribute on command line except by `dir /a:r` or `attrib`?

Answer (score 2):

Сlear read-only attribute:

```
X:\>attrib -R c10.dat
```

test:

```
X:\>dir > c10.dat
```

SKU:

ls -al

Output:

```
total 148
drwxrwxrwx+ 1 Domain Users     Domain Users      0 Apr  9 04:06 .
drwxrwxrwx+ 1 +Administrators  513               0 Apr  8 14:43 ..
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 +Administrators  Domain Users    354 Jun  5  2012 2.ps1
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 +Administrators  Domain Users    115 Oct 22 22:43 3.ps1
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 +Administrators  Domain Users    154 Apr  9 02:15 4.ps1
-r-xr-xr-x+ 1 +Administrators  Domain Users  12030 Apr  9 02:25 Aliases.txt
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 +Administrators  Domain Users    267 Feb 21  2012 ps-run.cmd
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 +Administrators  Domain Users  61436 Apr  9 04:07 sub2.txt
```

Comment: I am not trying to clear the read-only attribute, I am trying to understand how to identify that the file is read-only from icacls output

Comment: @HemalPandya With icacls probably does. It is a tool to manage the list of rights, and not the changes and view the simple attributes. `dir /A:R-D c10.dat | find /C /I "c10.dat"` or `dir /A:R-D c10.dat` Maybe I did not understand the question, and you are looking for effective rights for the user to provide a read-only use ACLs ...

Comment: I am trying to find a way to get a list of files along with their read-only status, something like `ls -al` on unix

Comment: @HemalPandya http://www.suacommunity.com/SUA.aspx may use SFU/SUA or server - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=274

Comment: thanks. I am already using `cygwin` on my machine that gives this information but I was looking for something pre-installed.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are confusing the **`Read-only`** attribute of a file with the **`ACL`** (as others have mentioned).

If a file is marked with the **`Read-only`** attribute (as can be seen by **`attrib`** or **`dir /a:r`**), it will be unwriteable **`(Read-only)`** by the system and all users regardless of the **`ACL`** permissions of the file for any user.

If you are trying to find the **`Write`** permission **`(ACL)`** of a file for a given user you will see that using **`icacls`**.

For example, I created a file named "test.txt". The file is NOT marked **`Read-only`**.

```
C:\>attrib test.txt
A            C:\test.txt

C:\>
```

I checked the file using **`icacls`**:

```
C:\>icacls test.txt
test.txt BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
         NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
         BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)

C:\>
```

I marked the file **`Read-only`** using **`attrib`**:

```
C:\>attrib +R test.txt
A    R       C:\test.txt

C:\>attrib test.txt
A    R       C:\test.txt

C:\>
```

I checked the file again using **`icacls`**:

```
C:\>icacls test.txt
test.txt BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
         NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
         BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)

C:\>
```

As you have seen, there is no change to the output of **`icacls`** for this file.

Then I changed the permission of the file for **`BUILTIN\Users`** to **`Deny Write`** (this approximates **`Read-only`**), and checked the file again using **`icacls`**:

```
C:\>icacls test.txt
test.txt BUILTIN\Users:(DENY)(W)
         BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
         NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
         BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)

C:\>
```

Notice that now, it shows **`BUILTIN\Users:(DENY)(W)`** for the file.

If I change the permission of the file for **`BUILTIN\Users`** to **`Deny Full control`** and check the file again **`icacls`** shows:

```
C:\>icacls test.txt
test.txt BUILTIN\Users:(N)
         BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
         NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
         BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)

C:\>
```

It now shows **`BUILTIN\Users:(N)`** for the file.

If I change the permission of the file for **`BUILTIN\Users`** to **`Allow Full control`** and then **`Deny Modify`** and check the file again **`icacls`** shows:

```
C:\>icacls test.txt
test.txt BUILTIN\Users:(DENY)(M)
         BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
         NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(I)(M)
         BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)

C:\>
```

It now shows **`BUILTIN\Users:(DENY)(M)`** for the file.

If you want to see the setting of the attribute "Read-only" for a file, you will not be able to see it using **`icacls`** because **`Read-only`** is not a part of the **`ACL`**. You should use **`attrib`**.

Comment: Thanks. I understood that ACL are different from readonly from the other answer; but thanks for taking the trouble of preparing detailed answer

Comment: Can you say why you don't want to (or can't) use **`attrib`** for this ?

Comment: I did not want to use attrib, because I had forgotten how it works. Now I am fine :)